Experience Cloud Community User only sees 1 of 21 records in a List View (Record List component)
In Salesforce, "Open Referrals" List View has 21 Records, and it has this filtering. Note it's filtering on Referring Person Email contains "@acme.org". Also, I'm sharing this List View with a Public Group (which has my Community User)

In Experience Cloud, I only see 6 of those records.

To try to fix this, I figured it's caused by the Permission Set on the Community User having FSL on "Referring Person Email" set to no read nor
edit. So I turned on Read only for this field. Now, the Community User only sees 1 of 21 records. Why would giving visibility to a field reduce amount of records for the Community User? Note, "@acme.org" here.

How do I get all 21 records showing for my Community User?

Fixed this with a Sharing Rule on the Referrals object.
Filter for Referrals where Submitting Person Email contains @acme.org
Give access to the Public Group (which has my Community User)
